# Not able to access dotnev variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I have added a `.env` file in my nodeJs application and post that added below line in my `app.js`

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

I still cannot access the environment variables. What's is missing here?

`.env` file content

```
PORT: 3000
SPACE:"dev"
Password: "ABC"
```

and I am trying to access it using

```
process.env.PORT
```

Which is coming as 'undefined'

Update `app.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors')
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config();')


process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;

app.use(express.json());

console.log(process.env.PORT)
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you share your `.env` file and the code you use the access the env vars?

Comment: how are you trying to access them? is the line executed before you try to access them? is the file with the line in the same directory as the `.env` file?

Comment: The `.env` file should in the root directory. Could you add more details to the question? Like error or any logs.

Comment: This is the way how you access them `process.env.PORT` and inside your .env file it should look like this `PORT=3001`

Comment: @PrathameshMore Its in the root directly

Comment: And you are getting `undefined` for `process.env.SPACE`? And you installed the dependency `dotenv` as well?

Comment: @Dominik yes, its coming as `undefined` and 'dotenv' is installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.env files should have params as:

```
SPACE=dev
Password=ABC
```

The examples are mentioned on the github [repo](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv).

Comment: still its coming as `undefined`

Comment: have you restart your server after changing .env file ?

Comment: yup, multiple times

Comment: can you share your app.js code so that I can try and identify issue there ?

Comment: I have updated my post with app.js code. please have a look.

Comment: You should call your dot env as soon as possible. so try initialising `const app = express()` after dotenv code.

Comment: Nothing changes unfortunaley

Answer (score 0):

Keep your .env file in the same path of your app.js(server.js/index.js or main.js whatever you name to your root file).

.env file

```
PORT=3000
SPACE=DEV
PASSWORD=ABC
```

app.js file

```
require('dotenv').config()

console.log(process.env.PORT)
console.log(process.env.SPACE)
console.log(process.env.PASSWORD)
```

file-path

```
/my-app
    app.js
    .env
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the path where your **.env** file is, like this

```
require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/../.env'});
```